# How to make a windows form app with a language?

Tags: c#

I mean that Visual C# can make a windows form app easily, but i want to know how C# can make WFA (because Visual C# just is a ide). how a Windows Application(not Console) can run in windows.

Comment: How to make a windows app without Net Framework (i see very much app don't need NETFRAMEWORK),

Comment: To make a windows app without .net framework, you can use C/C++, and change the tag C# of your question to C/C++.

Comment: If you wish to program with C#, you will need to use the .NET Framework. No way around that, for now at least.

Comment: @Snoob: So your question is *really* whether you can use C# without using the .NET framework - and the simple answer is "no". You can use Mono instead, but that's effectively another implementation of .NET.

Comment: How a C++ can make a windows form.

Comment: @Snoob: It sounds like you're after MFC then - but I'd strongly advise you to go for managed code instead. It's *much* simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you write exactly the same code as normal, but compile with:

```
csc /target:winexe (source files)
```

Of course if you've written everything in Visual Studio, you'll have designer files - but you *can* write everything manually. Here's a small WinForms Hello World app:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Hello
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form
        {
            Text = "Simple Windows Forms app",
            Controls = { new Label { Text = "Hello, world" } }
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Having mentioned the target switch earlier, I should point out that you don't *have* to use it - you can compile and run the code above using just

```
csc Hello.cs
```

I sometimes find that handy if I want to write a small test app which sends diagnostics to the console. It will start as a console app but still displays the form perfectly well.

Comment: Please Google (1) C++/Visual C++ (2) C#/Visual C#(what's this?)/Visual Studio

Comment: @Snoopy: Um, that *is* C#. The compiler comes up saying "Visual C#" but it doesn't require Visual Studio to be installed or anything like that. In fact, I've just tested that code on the machine I'm using, which currently doesn't have VS installed.

Comment: using System.Windows.Forms -> Is it a Netframework component?

Comment: @Snoob: Yes. Just as System.Int32, System.String etc are .NET types.

Comment: How C#/C++ can make a native windows app without Net ? (or without using System.Windows.Forms;)

Comment: @Snoob, by using the Win32 API directly and invoking that.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API

Comment: Thanks Filip Ekberg very much. Now i knew

Comment: @Snoob: Note that that will work for native C++, but *not* for C#.